# Проблема при использовании модуля pickle в Python

Tags: python, pickle

Мне  нужно, что бы в файл с расширением .data сохранялось и печаталось всё, что туда будет добавлено. Вот код:

```
a = input('Что вы хотите сделать?\n1) Добавить человека\n2) Пoсмотреть список записаных людей\n3) Изменить контакт\n4) Удалить контакт\n5) Найти контакт:  ')
alls = {}

if a == '1':
    name = input('Введие имя: ')
    age = input('Введите возвраст: ')
    number = input('Введите номер телефона: ')
    alls['Имя: ' + name]=('Возвраст: ' + age, 'Номер: ' + number)

    import pickle
    shoplistfile = 'friends.data'
    
    f = open(shoplistfile, "wb")
    pickle.dump(alls, f)
    f.close()

elif a == '2':
    import pickle
    shoplistfile = 'friends.data'
    
    f = open(shoplistfile, "rb")
    storedlist = pickle.load(f)
    print(storedlist)
```

Вот вводы и выводы:

````
Что вы хотите сделать?                                
1) Добавить человека                                  
2) Пoсмотреть список записанных людей                  
3) Изменить контакт                                   
4) Удалить контакт                                    
5) Найти контакт:  1                                  
Введите имя: Андрей                                    
Введите возраст: 23                                  
Введите номер телефона: +79280000000                  
                                                      
robbi@LAPTOP-QFJV9QIL C:\Users\robbi\main
$ python main.py                         
Что вы хотите сделать?                                
1) Добавить человека                                  
2) Пoсмотреть список записанных людей                  
3) Изменить контакт                                   
4) Удалить контакт                                    
5) Найти контакт:  1                                  
Введите имя: Иван                                      
Введите возраст: 32                                  
Введите номер телефона: +79031111111                  
                                                      
robbi@LAPTOP-QFJV9QIL C:\Users\robbi\main
$ python main.py                         
Что вы хотите сделать?                                
1) Добавить человека                                  
2) Пoсмотреть список записанных людей                  
3) Изменить контакт                                   
4) Удалить контакт                                    
5) Найти контакт:  2                                  
{'Имя: Иван': ('Возраст: 32', 'Номер: +79031111111')}
                                                      ```
Вместо wb ставил ab, так наоборот печатается первый элемент файла
````

Comment: При добавлении данных сначала прочитайте, что у вас в файле в память, добавьте туда данные и потом уже сохраните в файл.